# Is it possible to edit a GridView cell without an edititemtemplate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

```xml
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="lclick">Buy</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
    <edititemtemplate>
        <asp:Textbox runat="server" id="txt"/>
    <edititemtemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Is it possible to edit the `GridView` without the `edititem` Template?

Comment: You can do with javascript, so YES!

Comment: What you have tried ? And what you actually want ? You can actually use `Gridview's default edit button`. <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateEditButton ="true">    
</asp:GridView>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this before and I can only explain what I did

To make sure my edit controls is part of viewstate I added an empty form to the bottom of my page

```
<div id="myeditform">
   <table>
   <tr>
     <td><asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="myRowId" />
     </td>

     <td>... other controls </td>

     <td>... Save button -- </td>
   </tr>
   <table>
</div>
```

The tr(s) has to match the number of columns in your grid or you can use `colspan`

Then

- use jQuery or javascript to get the row (e.g. the nearest  parent to the edit link clicked),
- get the td(s) and pass the value of each `td` to the respective control in your edit form.
- replace your `<tr>` with the content of the table in your edit form
- when save is clicked, refresh the page to update gridview

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. That means, without Javascript/JQuery, it is not possible?

Comment: Yes without JavaScript you have to go the Asp.Net way, having EditItemTemplate (default or custom). The default shows textbox for all columns except the ones specified as read-only. To have dropdown and other controls as part of edit, you'll need to explicitly define the edit item template. The only difference from the Javascript version is there is no postback until you click save. and you can also use jQuery to perform transition between edit mode and view mode

Comment: Just want to make sure I'm understanding this correctly... if i have a form like a dropdown, and I want the user to be able to edit the values, it is *required* that they have to click the edit button first?